# Jquery on button click get the selected option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below. Trying to get the value of selected option but first one give error that test.parent is not a function and second variable get an empty string. How can I make this work?

```
<select unselectable="on" name="gender">
  <option value="Male" unselectable="on">Male</option>
  <option value="Female" unselectable="on">Female</option>
</select>
<input value="Submit" onclick="addItem(this)" type="button">

<script>
    function addItem(test){
        var selected_val1 = test.parent('#gender option:selected').val();
        var selected_val2 = $("#gender option:selected").text();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For the second one try `$("#gender option:selected").val()`

Comment: `gender` isn't an ID, but a name attribute. BTW, no need to target option selected, SELECT has its own value property matching the selected one. This question doesn't show much effort in searching, did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `this` to the `addItem()` function, and caching it as `test`, and that's not a jQuery object, but a native DOM node.

Then you're doing `test.parent('#gender option:selected').val();`, but `test` had no parent method, nor does it have a parent select element.

The select is the previous element, so you should be using `prev`

```
$(test).prev('[name="gender"]').find('option:selected').val();
```

or just

```
$(test).prev('select').val();
```

seems easier

Comment: I thought you said test has no parent

Comment: it has no `parent` **method**, as it's not a jQuery object.

Comment: but I meant as in test has no parent that's a select, oh there you go

Comment: @Huangism - you're right, I just changed it to `prev`

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected_val1 = $(test).parent().find('select[name="gender"] option:selected').val();
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/z96c7025/

Answer (score 0):

Inline JS is not recommended, so I would go with something like:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', addItem);

function addItem() {

    //in this callback 'this' refers to the button that was clicked and,
    //as @adeneo has rightly pointed out, it should be wrapped in $()
    var selected_val1 = $(this).prev().val(),
        selected_val2 = $(this).prev().find('option:selected').text();

    alert( 'value: ' + selected_val1 + ' text: ' + selected_val2 );
}
```

```js
$('#mybutton').on('click', addItem);

function addItem() {
  var selected_val1 = $(this).prev().val(),
      selected_val2 = $(this).prev().find('option:selected').text();
  alert( 'value: ' + selected_val1 + ' text: ' + selected_val2 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select unselectable="on" name="gender">
  <option value="Male" unselectable="on">Male</option>
  <option value="Female" unselectable="on">Female</option>
</select>
<input value="Submit" type="button" id="mybutton">
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, inline JS is not always a good choice, but if you choose to do so, these modifications should help. The javascript can be much, much more simple.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <select name="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <input value="Submit" onclick="addItem(this.form)" type="button">  </form>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function addItem(form) {
  console.log(form.gender.value)
}
```

**JS Extended**

```
function addItem(form) {

  var gender = form.gender;

  for ( var i=0; i<gender.length; i++) {
    console.log('Option ' + i + ': ' + form.gender[i].value)
  }
  console.log('Selected option: ' + form.gender.value);

  var unselectedIndex = ( form.gender.selectedIndex + (form.length - 1))

  console.log('Unselected option: ' + form.gender[unselectedIndex].value)
}
```